# Query code for finding highest value of collections?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm new to arango, and want to find the highest value(located in a content object) from a group of collections, i have tried to use MAX but that didn't work.

Comment: It is better to post your code, to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query with [AGGREGATE](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-collect.html#aggregation), which is an efficient way of finding the highest value:

```
FOR doc IN collection
  COLLECT AGGREGATE max = MAX(doc.value)
  RETURN max
```

If you want to return the document with the highest value, then you can sort in descending order and return the first document:

```
FOR doc IN collection
  SORT doc.value DESC
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN doc
```

Note that there could be multiple documents with the same highest value unless there is an index on the field with a uniqueness constraint. If you want to return all documents with the highest value, then you can first determine the highest value in a sub-query, then filter by that value:

```
LET max = FIRST(FOR doc IN collection COLLECT AGGREGATE max = MAX(doc.value) RETURN max)
FOR doc IN collection
  FILTER doc.value == max
  RETURN doc
```

Comment: Any idea why `RETURN MAX( collection[*].value )` doesn't work anymore?

Comment: It's forbidden because it is extremely inefficient - it loads all of the collection's data to get the values, and then has all the values in memory to determine the highest one instead of finding the highest one and only having highest value yet seen in memory at any time. Also see https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/release-notes-upgrading-changes39.html#disallowed-usage-of-collection-names-in-aql-expressions. Removed the example that used a collection in an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `SORT` and `LIMIT`. For example:

```
FOR c IN collection
  LIMIT 1
  SORT c._key DESC
  RETURN c
```

This will return highest value in the `_key` column. You can exchange it with another column.

Comment: This will not work. If a `LIMIT` operation is written before a `SORT` operation, then the limit is applied first, which here means you get one random document from the collection, then the sorting happens - which will do nothing because you fetched a single document. Furthermore, sorting by `_key` will not use the primary index in versions up to 3.4. Index utilization for `_key` will become available in v3.5.0 for RocksDB engine however.